# How can I publish an iOS app on the App Store, but disallow iPad compatibility?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, publish

I have an app that i specified **target devices as iPhone**, **not iPad, not Universal.**
Something strange happened when i look at the app information, on compatibility section, on App Store: it is said that the app is Compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod touch.

How can I remove the compatibility with iPad?

Comment: Did you add the screenshots for the iPad in app store?

Comment: No, only for iPhone, for all screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any iPhone app can be run on an iPad in an emulation mode. There is no (official) way to prevent this.

To test that your settings are correct, go to the App Store and search for your app with "iPad apps" set. If it doesn't show up, you're good to go.

You can still download this app on iTunes, or set the App Store to search iPad and iPhone and install it on an iPad, but it runs as an iPhone app on the iPad.

Comment: I'm not sure about nowadays, but some time ago WhatsApp was iPhone only, it was impossible to install it on iPad without jaibreak or some other hacks

Comment: That might have been some hack on the part of WhatsApp.

Comment: I've not tested it, but what happens if you add `telephony` to `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`? As I don't believe any iPads support this.

Comment: @JamesP THAT is a very good question. I don't have any way of testing that at the moment. Looks like this would restrict it, though Apple may get annoyed if you set this without actually needing telephony.

Comment: May be a good idea :D i'll try it and will give you a feedback.

Comment: @black4bird ok, if you get some solid data on that I'll update the answe.r

Answer (score 0):

That very unusual. There could be a lot things that could be causing this. You might want to check the provisioning file to see if there's anything a miss there. Also, check the certificate for the app as Well. It might be an idea to created a new certificate for the app. Other than that I don't know what else you could do.

Comment: On the itunes connect page, it shows iPhone/iPod touch, but on App Store, all devices are said to be compatible with.